# SQL Developer 4.1.1 trava em "Restaurando Janelas"

Tags: sqldeveloper

Baixei a versão 4.1.1 (4.1.1.19.59) do SQL Developer, mas depois do primeiro uso não consigo mais abri-lo. Ele trava no processo "Restaurando Janelas". Alguém passa pelo mesmo problema? Acharam a solução?
A única coisa que funcionou aqui até agora foi deletar os arquivos de histórico em AppData\Roaming.

Answer (score 1):

Solução: Instalação do JDK 8.0_45

Depois de instalado passou a funcionar normalmente.